# How to configure automatic folder assignment for document module in OpenERP 7?

Tags: odoo, openerp-7

I installed document and document-ftp modules in my OpenERP environment as described in the OpenERP documentation for [Document Management](https://doc.odoo.com/book/7/7_19_Documents/). Next I configured the `filestore` directory and printed some sample documents like quotations and invoices. All documents are created properly as attachments to the specific resource and appear also in the documents tree view and exists (with cryptic filenames) in the physical location `filestore/db_name/...`.

But I can't figure out on how to configure the automatic (virtual-)folder assignment, lets say, all quotations appear under the virtual folder `Sales Order/Quotations`. This does not work even for the folders of type `Folders per resource` which are installed by the module itself. The Field `Find all resources` is checked.

Goolge for this topic now for days did not lead to any result. The OpenERP documentation for [Document Management](https://doc.odoo.com/book/7/7_19_Documents/) is unclear to me as I followed all the steps properly and still no luck: All virtual folders remain empty.

Does the content for the folders of type `Folders per resource` needs to be generated somehow somewhere?

Please can anyone of you guys point me to the right direction of what I am missing here?

Comment: Update: accessing the documents from 'inside' a ssh session on the OpenERP server works: "ftp localhost:8021" enables me to log in with OpenERP users. However it is not possible to access the document_ftp server from 'outside'. (ftp 10.102.xy.xy:8021 fails with 'connection refused'). Please can someone out there help me?